# How can I make a PYTHON submodule directory with similar filenames as those in root import their OWN files with same names first

Tags: python, python-module, python-importlib

The title of this question may seem very confusing and I didn't know how to word it properly, but here's the gist of the situation.

Say I have this kind of file structure:

```
- main.py
- util.py
- submodules
  - module_folder
    - sub_main.py
    - util.py
```

main.py

```
import submodules.module_folder.sub_main
```

util.py

```
print("Util in root")
```

submodules/module_folder/sub_main.py

```
import util
```

submodules/module_folder/util.py

```
print("Util in submodules.module_folder.util")
```

The question is: How can I make `submodules/module_folder/sub_main.py`'s `import util` load `submodules/module_folder/util.py` instead of `util.py` in the root of the directory?

Restrictions:

- I can't change any files in module_folder. They are to be readonly

Application Context:
The reason that I want to build it this way is because I am building a feature that will let the user import arbitrary git submodules which can have random file structures and paths.

Comment: One way to do this is to add `submodules/module_folder` to path, and change the name of your `util.py` file in the root to avoid ambiguity. Otherwise, I think you have to change `sub_main` to use `import .util`, which you said is read-only and cannot be changed.

Comment: The intended and appropriate way to solve this problem is with relative imports, i.e., to change the way that the `import`s are done in the subfolder. *Why* exactly can't you change these?

Comment: Please start by reading the documentation for `sys.path` and make sure you understand *why* the existing code imports the way that it does.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The reason that I want to build it this way is because I am building a feature that will let the user import arbitrary git submodules which can have random file structures and paths. It would be nice if the user does not need to change anything on their side and just make this work out of the box.

Comment: You can modify `sys.path` from within `main.py`, assuming that this is an "entry point" and will always be run first. That will allow `sub_main` to import from the local folder first. However, this must happen before `sub_main` runs; and it runs because `main` imports it; so now `main.py` will say just `import sub_main` instead. It also needs to happen *after* `main.py` does its *other* imports (or else restore `sys.path` first).

Comment: I was looking into sys.path and sys.meta_path. I'm trying to see if I can make some sort of custom loader or filefinder that can take these restrictions into mind

Comment: @Karl Knechtel yea that's an interesting idea. Might have to tinker with it

Comment: "that will let the user import arbitrary git submodules which can have random file structures and paths." How do you intend to secure this against, for example, that code trying to `import` things blindly that aren't within its own code nor the standard library? You are going to want to hook into the loading process; while you're at it, check out techniques for loading a module dynamically (i.e., from a file path, not from a module name).

Comment: But in any event, please try to edit the question to make the context understandable; and try to [do some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) first.